# Inserting a BeautifulSoup object into another

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hey guys so what im tryng to do is insert the content of a html page into another page using beautiful soup

```
with open("testpage.html") as fp:
    mainSoup = BeautifulSoup(fp)

with open("navbarContent.html") as fp:
    extraSoup = BeautifulSoup(fp)

for elm in mainSoup.find_all('nav', {"id":"sidebar"}):
    elm.string= str(extraSoup)
```

So i want the html content of the navbarContent.html to be inserted in the testpage.html in  the  tag.
Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You can add the html code in triple quotes like this:

```
htmlCode = ´´´
<html>
</html>
´´´
```

then add the content of the navbarContent to it and then you can write the whole thing into the html file again using `write()`.

But first you have to `open()` and after you have to `close()` the file.
I hope you know how that works.